# Getting has_permission() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view' instead of JSON Response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[image]

1. Getting has_permission() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view' instead of JSON Response

   from rest_framework import filters
   from rest_framework import viewsets
   from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

   from apps.fm.models.asset import Asset
   from apps.fm.serializers import AssetSerializer
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
   from django.urls import reverse

   class AssetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   model = Asset
   serializer_class = AssetSerializer
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
   filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
   search_fields = ['name']
   ordering_fields = ['id']
   ordering = ['-id']

   ```
   def get_permissions(self):
       uagent = ['Chrome','Firefox']
       if self.request.user_agent.browser.family in uagent:
           return []

       return [IsAuthenticated] 

   def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       instance = self.get_object()
       uagent = ['Chrome','Firefox']

       if self.request.user_agent.browser.family in uagent:
           authentication_classes = [] #disables authentication
           permission_classes = [] #disables permission

           return redirect(reverse("feedback")+"?type=Asset&id="+str(instance.id))

       serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)

       return Response(serializer.data)    


   def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = self.model.objects.all()
       return queryset
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`get_permissions` should return instances of your permission classes, you are currently returning the class instead

```
def get_permissions(self):
    uagent = ['Chrome','Firefox']
    if self.request.user_agent.browser.family in uagent:
        return []
    return [IsAuthenticated()] # Create an instance of the permission class
```

Or better yet, since you have set `permission_classes` on the ViewSet you can just call `super`

```
def get_permissions(self):
    uagent = ['Chrome','Firefox']
    if self.request.user_agent.browser.family in uagent:
        return []
    return super().get_permissions()
```